# Error in creating a function in a database which updates 3 tables at oncw

Tags: mysql, database, function

I have created a database in mysql with these tables, recipes, ingredients, and a bridging table for recipe and ingredients. But its not working. This is the query

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE add_recipe (
    IN recipe_name VARCHAR(255),
    IN cooking_time TIME,
    IN serving_size INT,
    IN instructions TEXT,
    IN category_id INT,
    IN ingredients_list TEXT
)
BEGIN
    -- Check if recipe already exists
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipe_name = recipe_name) THEN
        SELECT 'Recipe already exists';
    ELSE
        -- Insert recipe into recipes table
        INSERT INTO recipes (recipe_name, cooking_time, serving_size, instructions, category_id)
        VALUES (recipe_name, cooking_time, serving_size, instructions, category_id);
        
        -- Get the recipe_id of the newly added recipe
        SET @recipe_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        
        -- Split the ingredients list by comma
        SET @ingredients = TRIM(ingredients_list);
        WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(@ingredients) > 0 DO
            SET @comma_position = LOCATE(',', @ingredients);
            IF @comma_position = 0 THEN
                SET @ingredient_name = TRIM(@ingredients);
                SET @ingredients = '';
            ELSE
                SET @ingredient_name = TRIM(LEFT(@ingredients, @comma_position - 1));
                SET @ingredients = SUBSTRING(@ingredients, @comma_position + 1);
            END IF;
            
            -- Check if the ingredient already exists
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = @ingredient_name) THEN
                -- If the ingredient doesn't exist, add it to the ingredients table
                INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient_name) VALUES (@ingredient_name);
            END IF;
            
            -- Get the ingredient_id of the ingredient
            SET @ingredient_id = (SELECT ingredient_id FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient_name = @ingredient_name);
            
            -- Add the ingredient to the recipe_ingredients table
            INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) VALUES (@recipe_id, @ingredient_id);
        END WHILE;
        
        SELECT 'Recipe added successfully';
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Its entering the data in recipes and in recipe_ingredient but not in ingredient. Its also not checking if the ingredient is already available in database.

Comment: 'but not in ingredient' - you are inserting to ingredients?  and selecting from ingredients? A typo somewhere but I don't know where..